# Which HTTP status code is recommended for application errors in a REST service?

Tags: rest, http-status-code-404

The service might have various application errors as response. Which HTTP Status code is recommended for these error responses? And how do we decide on which HTTP status code to be used for application errors? As I understand, each status code is meant for a specific scenario/failure. Hows the status codes and application errors correlate?

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly you want to know which status code to use in which case?

Best way i guess is to take a look at the [RFC](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

There are also examples written there.

e.g.

If your application "error" is that the user is not authenticated use "401", if it is some sort of "fatal error" (worst case i guess) the RFC says return a status code starting with 5.x.x (Depending on the error)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, in REST services (Dropbox api, Amazon API, Mailchimp, ...) any precise errors specific to the application are given in a standard http response in a specific format (json, rpc, xml, ...).

For instant check here for [amazon-drive](https://developer.amazon.com/fr/docs/amazon-drive/ad-restful-api-response-codes.html), and [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation).

As you can see Dropbox uses HTTP error code 409 and tells the user to look for the field error and `error_summary`. Having said that, the purpose of an HTTP response should be informative and understandable in a standard way (not only to you and machines, but also to fellow developers.) You would find it beneficial to familiarize yourself with the [MDN- Status Codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)